# Find specific words in text file and print the line using Python

Tags: python

I have a text file contain like this :

> Saya makan nasi padang semalam. Lauk yang aku pesan adalah ikan gurame. Harganya mahal. Aku juga makan dengan ayah dan ibuku. Setelah itu, Rina datang menemuiku.

And I want to find specific word in the text file and then print the sentence contain the specific words. I have many specific words. I try to code like this:

```
with open("kalimat.txt",'r') as f:
text = f.read()
# f.close()

words = ["makan","Rina","mahal"]

for item in text.split("\n"):
  if words in item:
    print(item.strip())
```

And I got error **TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list.**
How to print sentences that have many specific words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def my_function():


  with open("exampleValues",'r') as f, open('output.txt','w') as fw:
      text = f.read()
      result_string = ''

      words = ["makan", "Rina", "mahal"]
      text2 = text.split(".")
      for itemIndex in range(len(text2)):
          for word in words:
              if word in text2[itemIndex]:
                  if text2[itemIndex][0] ==' ':
                      print(text2[itemIndex][1:])
                      result_string += text2[itemIndex][1:]+'. '
                      break
                  else:
                      print(text2[itemIndex])
                      result_string += text2[itemIndex]
                      break
      print(result_string)
      fw.write(result_string)

my_function()
```

If this useful. Don't forget vote me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to print the sentences, you should split the paragraph using "."

```
sentences = text.split('.')
for sentence in sentences :
     for word in words :
           if word in sentence :
                print (sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_function():

  with open("exampleValues",'r') as f:
      text = f.read()
      words = ["makan", "Rina", "mahal"]
      text2 = text.split("\n")
      for itemIndex in range(len(text2)):
          if words[0] in text2[itemIndex] or words[1] in text2[itemIndex] or 
words[2] in text2[itemIndex]:
                  print(text2[itemIndex].strip())
my_function()
```

I found if use Samraj Moorjani's logic, if we try put two or three words in same line, this line will be output 2 or 3 times. Hope my code is useful.

Comment: My if.. sentences looks stupid, you can rewrite them

Comment: The way you wrote your code, the if statement will grow if the words array contain 20 words. Can't you just loop over the words and break out of it and move to the next sentence as soon as found?

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_function():

  with open("exampleValues",'r') as f:
      text = f.read()
      words = ["makan", "Rina", "mahal"]
      text2 = text.split("\n")
      for itemIndex in range(len(text2)):
          for word in words:
              if word in text2[itemIndex]:
                  print(text2[itemIndex])
                  break
my_function()
```

This answer will be more useful than my above answer. Thanks alvits.

Comment: yeah, for sentences, split(".") more useful, just change split('\n')

Comment: Hey, i tried your code and it's work. But at the beginning of the sentence there is whitespace (space). How to remove whitespace? And how can I print the output to **.txt** file? Where I put the print code into a **.txt** file? Could you write for me. @JackChen

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sets:

```
with open("kalimat.txt",'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

search_words = set(["makan","Rina","mahal"])

for sentence in text.split("."):
    words_in_sentence = set(sentence.split())
    if words_in_sentence.intersection(search_words):
        print(sentence)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't search for a list in a string. You need to look for a string within a string. Use index notation to search for each item in the list.

```
for item in text.split("."):
    for index in range (0,len(words)):
        if words[index] in item:
            print(item.strip())
```

You can take it from there and also make sure to account for multiple words in a single sentence by breaking out of the loop.

**Edit**

Changed "\n" to "."

Comment: you don't need lines, but sentences, split using `.` (dot) as a separator, not the newline.